# Deploy war file in Payara 5 Docker container

Tags: java, docker, war, payara

I'm having trouble getting my war file to deploy on application start.

According to the docs [here](https://docs.payara.fish/community/docs/documentation/ecosystem/docker-images/server-image-overview.html#deploy-using-custom-image):

*The following sample Dockerfile can be used to prepare a custom Payara Server image that deploys the myapplication.war artefact at runtime:*

```
FROM payara/server-full
COPY myapplication.war $DEPLOY_DIR
```

*And to launch the container, simply build and run the image like this:*

```
docker build -t mycompany/myapplication:1.0 .
docker run -p 8080:8080 mycompany/myapplication:1.0
```

But when I run the container, it doesn't try and deploy the application unless I restart the container. Am I missing something here? I'd expect the container to try and deploy the application from a fresh boot, every time, otherwise it kind of defeats the point of ephemeral containers?

These are the logs from docker desktop (Version: 4.0.0, Engine: 20.10.8), i've seperated the logs but they all come from the same file. I also had to remove some of the INFO logs due to post limits:

### First start

```bash
    [Entrypoint] running /opt/payara/scripts/init_1_generate_deploy_commands.sh
    Adding deployment target /opt/payara/deployments/icat.server-4.11.1.war to post boot commands
    
    [Entrypoint] ignoring /opt/payara/scripts/init.d/*
    
    Executing Payara Server with the following command line:
    /usr/lib/jvm/zulu8-ca-amd64/bin/java
    -cp
    /opt/payara/appserver/glassfish/modules/glassfish.jar
    -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions
    -XX:NewRatio=2
    -XX:+UseContainerSupport
    -XX:MaxRAMPercentage=70.0
    -Xbootclasspath/a:/opt/payara/appserver/glassfish/lib/grizzly-npn-api.jar
    -Xss512k
    -server
    -javaagent:/opt/payara/appserver/glassfish/lib/monitor/flashlight-agent.jar
    -Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all
    -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/opt/payara/appserver/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/cacerts.jks
    -Djdk.tls.rejectClientInitiatedRenegotiation=true
    -Djdk.corba.allowOutputStreamSubclass=true
    -Dfelix.fileinstall.dir=/opt/payara/appserver/glassfish/modules/autostart/
    -Dorg.glassfish.additionalOSGiBundlesToStart=org.apache.felix.shell,org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime,org.apache.felix.gogo.shell,org.apache.felix.gogo.command,org.apache.felix.shell.remote,org.apache.felix.fileinstall
    -Dcom.sun.aas.installRoot=/opt/payara/appserver/glassfish
    -Dfelix.fileinstall.poll=5000
    -Djava.security.policy=/opt/payara/appserver/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/server.policy
    -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/opt/payara/appserver/glassfish/modules/endorsed:/opt/payara/appserver/glassfish/lib/endorsed
    -Dosgi.shell.telnet.maxconn=1
    -Dfelix.fileinstall.bundles.startTransient=true
    -Dcom.sun.enterprise.config.config_environment_factory_class=com.sun.enterprise.config.serverbeans.AppserverConfigEnvironmentFactory
    -Dfelix.fileinstall.log.level=2
    -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/opt/payara/appserver/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/keystore.jks
    -Djava.security.auth.login.config=/opt/payara/appserver/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/login.conf
    -Dfelix.fileinstall.disableConfigSave=false
    -Dorg.glassfish.grizzly.DEFAULT_MEMORY_MANAGER=org.glassfish.grizzly.memory.HeapMemoryManager
    -Dfelix.fileinstall.bundles.new.start=true
    -Dcom.sun.aas.instanceRoot=/opt/payara/appserver/glassfish/domains/domain1
    -Dosgi.shell.telnet.port=6666
    -Dgosh.args=--nointeractive
    -Dcom.sun.enterprise.security.httpsOutboundKeyAlias=s1as
    -Dorg.jboss.weld.serialization.beanIdentifierIndexOptimization=false
    -Dosgi.shell.telnet.ip=127.0.0.1
    -DANTLR_USE_DIRECT_CLASS_LOADING=true
    -Djava.awt.headless=true
    -Dcom.ctc.wstx.returnNullForDefaultNamespace=true
    -Djava.ext.dirs=/usr/lib/jvm/zulu8-ca-amd64/lib/ext:/usr/lib/jvm/zulu8-ca-amd64/jre/lib/ext:/opt/payara/appserver/glassfish/domains/domain1/lib/ext
    -Djdbc.drivers=org.h2.Driver
    -Dorg.glassfish.grizzly.nio.DefaultSelectorHandler.force-selector-spin-detection=true
    -Djava.library.path=/opt/payara/appserver/glassfish/lib:/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
    com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.ASMain
    -prebootcommandfile
    /opt/payara/config/pre-boot-commands-final.asadmin
    -upgrade
    false
    -read-stdin
    true
    -postbootcommandfile
    /opt/payara/config/post-boot-commands-final.asadmin
    -domainname
    domain1
    -domaindir
    /opt/payara/appserver/glassfish/domains/domain1
    -asadmin-args
    --host,,,localhost,,,--port,,,4848,,,--user,,,admin,,,--passwordfile,,,/opt/payara/passwordFile,,,--secure=false,,,--terse=false,,,--extraterse=false,,,--echo=false,,,--interactive=false,,,--autoname=false,,,start-domain,,,--verbose=false,,,--watchdog=false,,,--debug=false,,,--domaindir,,,/opt/payara/appserver/glassfish/domains,,,domain1
    -instancename
    server
    -type
    DAS
    -verbose
    false
    -asadmin-classpath
    /opt/payara/appserver/glassfish/lib/client/appserver-cli.jar
    -debug
    false
    -asadmin-classname
    com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.AdminMain
    -watchdog
    false
    
    Launching Payara Server on Felix platform
    Registered com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishRuntime@aa74710 in service registry.
    Reading in commandments from /opt/payara/config/pre-boot-commands-final.asadmin
    
    
    
    #!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : rootFolder=/opt/payara/appserver/glassfish
    #!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : templateDir=/opt/payara/appserver/glassfish/lib/templates
    #!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : src=/opt/payara/appserver/glassfish/lib/templates/logging.properties
    #!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : dest=/opt/payara/appserver/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/logging.properties
    Sep 09, 2021 11:42:02 AM com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner createBundleProvisioner
    INFO: Create bundle provisioner class = class com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner.
    [#|2021-09-09T11:42:05.625+0000|INFO|Payara 5.2021.6|javax.enterprise.logging|_ThreadID=26;_ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1631187725519;_TimeMillis=1631187725625;_LevelValue=800;_MessageID=NCLS-LOGGING-00009;|
      Running Payara Version: Payara Server  5.2021.6 #badassfish (build 4579)|#]
    
    [#|2021-09-09T11:42:05.632+0000|INFO|Payara 5.2021.6|javax.enterprise.logging|_ThreadID=26;_ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1631187725519;_TimeMillis=1631187725632;_LevelValue=800;_MessageID=NCLS-LOGGING-00010;|
      Server log file is using Formatter class: com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.ODLLogFormatter|#]
    
    [#|2021-09-09T11:42:06.248+0000|INFO|Payara 5.2021.6|org.glassfish.ha.store.spi.BackingStoreFactoryRegistry|_ThreadID=27;_ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1631187725525;_TimeMillis=1631187726248;_LevelValue=800;|
      Registered fish.payara.ha.hazelcast.store.HazelcastBackingStoreFactoryProxy for persistence-type = hazelcast in BackingStoreFactoryRegistry|#]
    
    [#|2021-09-09T11:42:08.983+0000|INFO|Payara 5.2021.6|fish.payara.nucleus.hazelcast.HazelcastCore|_ThreadID=26;_ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1631187725519;_TimeMillis=1631187728983;_LevelValue=800;|
      Hazelcast Instance Bound to JNDI at payara/Hazelcast|#]
    
    [#|2021-09-09T11:42:08.983+0000|INFO|Payara 5.2021.6|fish.payara.nucleus.hazelcast.HazelcastCore|_ThreadID=26;_ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1631187725519;_TimeMillis=1631187728983;_LevelValue=800;|
      JSR107 Caching Provider Bound to JNDI at payara/CachingProvider|#]
    [#|2021-09-09T11:42:09.165+0000|INFO|Payara 5.2021.6|javax.enterprise.system.core|_ThreadID=25;_ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1631187725518;_TimeMillis=1631187729165;_LevelValue=800;_MessageID=NCLS-CORE-00101;|
      Network Listener http-listener-2 started in: 4ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8181]|#]
    
    [#|2021-09-09T11:42:09.185+0000|WARNING|Payara 5.2021.6|org.glassfish.grizzly.config.GenericGrizzlyListener|_ThreadID=25;_ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1631187725518;_TimeMillis=1631187729185;_LevelValue=900;|
      HTTP/2 (enabled by default) is unsupported with port unification and will be disabled for network listener admin-listener.|#]
    
    [#|2021-09-09T11:42:09.202+0000|INFO|Payara 5.2021.6|javax.enterprise.system.core|_ThreadID=25;_ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1631187725518;_TimeMillis=1631187729202;_LevelValue=800;_MessageID=NCLS-CORE-00101;|
      Network Listener admin-listener started in: 4ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:4848]|#]
    
    [#|2021-09-09T11:42:09.205+0000|INFO|Payara 5.2021.6|javax.enterprise.system.core|_ThreadID=25;_ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1631187725518;_TimeMillis=1631187729205;_LevelValue=800;_MessageID=NCLS-CORE-00087;|
      Grizzly 2.4.4 started in: 3,059ms - bound to [http-listener-1:8080, http-listener-2:8181, admin-listener:4848]|#]
    
    [#|2021-09-09T11:42:09.210+0000|INFO|Payara 5.2021.6|org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version|_ThreadID=27;_ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1631187725525;_TimeMillis=1631187729210;_LevelValue=800;|
      HV000001: Hibernate Validator 6.1.5.Final|#]
    
    [#|2021-09-09T11:42:09.276+0000|INFO|Payara 5.2021.6|javax.enterprise.system.core|_ThreadID=26;_ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1631187725519;_TimeMillis=1631187729276;_LevelValue=800;_MessageID=NCLS-CORE-00101;|
      Network Listener iiop-service started in: 3ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:3700]|#]
    
    [#|2021-09-09T11:42:09.840+0000|INFO|Payara 5.2021.6|fish.payara.nucleus.cluster.PayaraCluster|_ThreadID=84;_ThreadName=Executor-Service-3;_TimeMillis=1631187729840;_LevelValue=800;|
      Data Grid Status 
    Payara Data Grid State: DG Version: 4 DG Name: development DG Size: 1
    Instances: {
     DataGrid: development Name: server Lite: false This: true UUID: 7852ba25-994d-48a0-b88c-2a739f1abbda Address: /172.17.0.2:4900
    }|#]
    
    [#|2021-09-09T11:42:09.841+0000|INFO|Payara 5.2021.6|javax.enterprise.system.core|_ThreadID=1;_ThreadName=main;_TimeMillis=1631187729841;_LevelValue=800;_MessageID=NCLS-CORE-00017;|
      Payara Server  5.2021.6 #badassfish (4579) startup time : Felix (2,796ms), startup services(4,332ms), total(7,128ms)|#]
    
    [#|2021-09-09T11:42:09.853+0000|INFO|Payara 5.2021.6|fish.payara.nucleus.notification.NotificationService|_ThreadID=1;_ThreadName=main;_TimeMillis=1631187729853;_LevelValue=800;|
      Payara Notification Service bootstrapped.|#]
    
    [#|2021-09-09T11:42:09.873+0000|INFO|Payara 5.2021.6|monitoring-console-core|_ThreadID=1;_ThreadName=main;_TimeMillis=1631187729873;_LevelValue=800;|
      Bootstrapping Monitoring Console Runtime|#]
    
    [#|2021-09-09T11:42:09.912+0000|INFO|Payara 5.2021.6|monitoring-console-core|_ThreadID=1;_ThreadName=main;_TimeMillis=1631187729912;_LevelValue=800;|
      Starting monitoring data collection for server|#]
    
    [#|2021-09-09T11:42:09.913+0000|INFO|Payara 5.2021.6|monitoring-console-core|_ThreadID=1;_ThreadName=main;_TimeMillis=1631187729913;_LevelValue=800;|
      Starting monitoring watch collection for server|#]
    
    [#|2021-09-09T11:42:10.088+0000|INFO|Payara 5.2021.6|javax.enterprise.system.core|_ThreadID=25;_ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1631187725518;_TimeMillis=1631187730088;_LevelValue=800;_MessageID=NCLS-CORE-00101;|
      Network Listener JMS_PROXY_default_JMS_host started in: 2ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:7676]|#]
    
    [#|2021-09-09T11:42:10.096+0000|INFO|Payara 5.2021.6||_ThreadID=1;_ThreadName=main;_TimeMillis=1631187730096;_LevelValue=800;|
      Reading in commandments from /opt/payara/config/post-boot-commands-final.asadmin|#]
    
    [#|2021-09-09T11:42:10.232+0000|INFO|Payara 5.2021.6|org.jvnet.hk2.osgiadapter|_ThreadID=20;_ThreadName=FelixStartLevel;_TimeMillis=1631187730232;_LevelValue=800;|
      Skipping registration of inhabitant for service reference [org.osgi.service.metatype.MetaTypeProvider] as the service object could not be obtained.|#]
    
    [#|2021-09-09T11:42:10.260+0000|INFO|Payara 5.2021.6|javax.enterprise.system.jmx|_ThreadID=124;_ThreadName=Thread-14;_TimeMillis=1631187730260;_LevelValue=800;_MessageID=NCLS-JMX-00024;|
      Creating a SecureRMIServerSocketFactory @ 0.0.0.0 with ssl config = GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.grizzly.config.dom.Ssl|#]
    
    [#|2021-09-09T11:42:10.267+0000|WARNING|Payara 5.2021.6|javax.enterprise.system.jmx|_ThreadID=124;_ThreadName=Thread-14;_TimeMillis=1631187730267;_LevelValue=900;_MessageID=NCLS-JMX-00020;|
      All SSL cipher suites disabled for network-listener(s).  Using SSL implementation specific defaults|#]
    
    [#|2021-09-09T11:42:10.275+0000|WARNING|Payara 5.2021.6|javax.enterprise.system.jmx|_ThreadID=124;_ThreadName=Thread-14;_TimeMillis=1631187730275;_LevelValue=900;_MessageID=NCLS-JMX-00020;|
      All SSL cipher suites disabled for network-listener(s).  Using SSL implementation specific defaults|#]
```

### Second start

by stopping the container and starting it again:

```bash
    [Entrypoint] running /opt/payara/scripts/init_1_generate_deploy_commands.sh
    post boot commands already deploys /opt/payara/deployments/icat.server-4.11.1.war
    
    [Entrypoint] ignoring /opt/payara/scripts/init.d/*
    
    [#|2021-09-09T11:42:10.346+0000|INFO|Payara 5.2021.6|javax.enterprise.system.jmx|_ThreadID=124;_ThreadName=Thread-14;_TimeMillis=1631187730346;_LevelValue=800;_MessageID=NCLS-JMX-00025;|
      SSLServerSocket /0.0.0.0:8686 and [SSL: ServerSocket[addr=/0.0.0.0,localport=8686]] created|#]
    
    [#|2021-09-09T11:42:10.708+0000|INFO|Payara 5.2021.6|javax.enterprise.system.jmx|_ThreadID=124;_ThreadName=Thread-14;_TimeMillis=1631187730708;_LevelValue=800;_MessageID=NCLS-JMX-00005;|
      JMXStartupService has started JMXConnector on JMXService URL service:jmx:rmi://0.0.0.0:8686/jndi/rmi://0.0.0.0:8686/jmxrmi|#]
    
    Executing Payara Server with the following command line:
    /usr/lib/jvm/zulu8-ca-amd64/bin/java
    -cp
    /opt/payara/appserver/glassfish/modules/glassfish.jar
    -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions
    -XX:NewRatio=2
    -XX:+UseContainerSupport
    -XX:MaxRAMPercentage=70.0
    -Xbootclasspath/a:/opt/payara/appserver/glassfish/lib/grizzly-npn-api.jar
    -Xss512k
    -server
    -javaagent:/opt/payara/appserver/glassfish/lib/monitor/flashlight-agent.jar
    -Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all
    -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/opt/payara/appserver/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/cacerts.jks
    -Djdk.tls.rejectClientInitiatedRenegotiation=true
    -Djdk.corba.allowOutputStreamSubclass=true
    -Dfelix.fileinstall.dir=/opt/payara/appserver/glassfish/modules/autostart/
    -Dorg.glassfish.additionalOSGiBundlesToStart=org.apache.felix.shell,org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime,org.apache.felix.gogo.shell,org.apache.felix.gogo.command,org.apache.felix.shell.remote,org.apache.felix.fileinstall
    -Dcom.sun.aas.installRoot=/opt/payara/appserver/glassfish
    -Dfelix.fileinstall.poll=5000
    -Djava.security.policy=/opt/payara/appserver/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/server.policy
    -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/opt/payara/appserver/glassfish/modules/endorsed:/opt/payara/appserver/glassfish/lib/endorsed
    -Dosgi.shell.telnet.maxconn=1
    -Dfelix.fileinstall.bundles.startTransient=true
    -Dcom.sun.enterprise.config.config_environment_factory_class=com.sun.enterprise.config.serverbeans.AppserverConfigEnvironmentFactory
    -Dfelix.fileinstall.log.level=2
    -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/opt/payara/appserver/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/keystore.jks
    -Djava.security.auth.login.config=/opt/payara/appserver/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/login.conf
    -Dfelix.fileinstall.disableConfigSave=false
    -Dorg.glassfish.grizzly.DEFAULT_MEMORY_MANAGER=org.glassfish.grizzly.memory.HeapMemoryManager
    -Dfelix.fileinstall.bundles.new.start=true
    -Dcom.sun.aas.instanceRoot=/opt/payara/appserver/glassfish/domains/domain1
    -Dosgi.shell.telnet.port=6666
    -Dgosh.args=--nointeractive
    -Dcom.sun.enterprise.security.httpsOutboundKeyAlias=s1as
    -Dorg.jboss.weld.serialization.beanIdentifierIndexOptimization=false
    -Dosgi.shell.telnet.ip=127.0.0.1
    -DANTLR_USE_DIRECT_CLASS_LOADING=true
    -Djava.awt.headless=true
    -Dcom.ctc.wstx.returnNullForDefaultNamespace=true
    -Djava.ext.dirs=/usr/lib/jvm/zulu8-ca-amd64/lib/ext:/usr/lib/jvm/zulu8-ca-amd64/jre/lib/ext:/opt/payara/appserver/glassfish/domains/domain1/lib/ext
    -Djdbc.drivers=org.h2.Driver
    -Dorg.glassfish.grizzly.nio.DefaultSelectorHandler.force-selector-spin-detection=true
    -Djava.library.path=/opt/payara/appserver/glassfish/lib:/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
    com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.ASMain
    -prebootcommandfile
    /opt/payara/config/pre-boot-commands-final.asadmin
    -upgrade
    false
    -read-stdin
    true
    -postbootcommandfile
    /opt/payara/config/post-boot-commands-final.asadmin
    -domainname
    domain1
    -domaindir
    /opt/payara/appserver/glassfish/domains/domain1
    -asadmin-args
    --host,,,localhost,,,--port,,,4848,,,--user,,,admin,,,--passwordfile,,,/opt/payara/passwordFile,,,--secure=false,,,--terse=false,,,--extraterse=false,,,--echo=false,,,--interactive=false,,,--autoname=false,,,start-domain,,,--verbose=false,,,--watchdog=false,,,--debug=false,,,--domaindir,,,/opt/payara/appserver/glassfish/domains,,,domain1
    -instancename
    server
    -type
    DAS
    -verbose
    false
    -asadmin-classpath
    /opt/payara/appserver/glassfish/lib/client/appserver-cli.jar
    -debug
    false
    -asadmin-classname
    com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.AdminMain
    -watchdog
    false
    
    Launching Payara Server on Felix platform
    Sep 09, 2021 11:42:27 AM com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner createBundleProvisioner
    Registered com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishRuntime@2f34de61 in service registry.
    Reading in commandments from /opt/payara/config/pre-boot-commands-final.asadmin
    
    
    
    #!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : rootFolder=/opt/payara/appserver/glassfish
    #!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : templateDir=/opt/payara/appserver/glassfish/lib/templates
    #!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : src=/opt/payara/appserver/glassfish/lib/templates/logging.properties
    #!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : dest=/opt/payara/appserver/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/logging.properties
    [#|2021-09-09T11:42:32.497+0000|INFO|Payara 5.2021.6|javax.enterprise.system.core|_ThreadID=27;_ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1631187749117;_TimeMillis=1631187752497;_LevelValue=800;_MessageID=NCLS-CORE-00101;|
      Network Listener http-listener-2 started in: 13ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8181]|#]
    
    [#|2021-09-09T11:42:32.510+0000|INFO|Payara 5.2021.6|org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version|_ThreadID=26;_ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1631187749111;_TimeMillis=1631187752510;_LevelValue=800;|
      HV000001: Hibernate Validator 6.1.5.Final|#]
    
    [#|2021-09-09T11:42:32.525+0000|WARNING|Payara 5.2021.6|org.glassfish.grizzly.config.GenericGrizzlyListener|_ThreadID=27;_ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1631187749117;_TimeMillis=1631187752525;_LevelValue=900;|
      HTTP/2 (enabled by default) is unsupported with port unification and will be disabled for network listener admin-listener.|#]
    
    [#|2021-09-09T11:42:32.550+0000|INFO|Payara 5.2021.6|javax.enterprise.system.core|_ThreadID=27;_ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1631187749117;_TimeMillis=1631187752550;_LevelValue=800;_MessageID=NCLS-CORE-00101;|
      Network Listener admin-listener started in: 12ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:4848]|#]
    
    [#|2021-09-09T11:42:32.552+0000|INFO|Payara 5.2021.6|javax.enterprise.system.core|_ThreadID=27;_ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1631187749117;_TimeMillis=1631187752552;_LevelValue=800;_MessageID=NCLS-CORE-00087;|
      Grizzly 2.4.4 started in: 2,883ms - bound to [http-listener-1:8080, http-listener-2:8181, admin-listener:4848]|#]
    
    [#|2021-09-09T11:42:32.618+0000|INFO|Payara 5.2021.6|javax.enterprise.system.core|_ThreadID=28;_ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1631187749118;_TimeMillis=1631187752618;_LevelValue=800;_MessageID=NCLS-CORE-00101;|
      Network Listener iiop-service started in: 2ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:3700]|#]
    
    [#|2021-09-09T11:42:33.097+0000|INFO|Payara 5.2021.6|fish.payara.nucleus.cluster.PayaraCluster|_ThreadID=82;_ThreadName=Executor-Service-2;_TimeMillis=1631187753097;_LevelValue=800;|
      Data Grid Status 
    Payara Data Grid State: DG Version: 4 DG Name: development DG Size: 1
    Instances: {
     DataGrid: development Name: server Lite: false This: true UUID: 672559df-3c53-4feb-a1c6-9e44fefaf020 Address: /172.17.0.2:4900
    }|#]
    
    [#|2021-09-09T11:42:33.098+0000|INFO|Payara 5.2021.6|javax.enterprise.system.core|_ThreadID=1;_ThreadName=main;_TimeMillis=1631187753098;_LevelValue=800;_MessageID=NCLS-CORE-00017;|
      Payara Server  5.2021.6 #badassfish (4579) startup time : Felix (2,070ms), startup services(3,994ms), total(6,064ms)|#]
    
    [#|2021-09-09T11:42:33.113+0000|INFO|Payara 5.2021.6|fish.payara.nucleus.notification.NotificationService|_ThreadID=1;_ThreadName=main;_TimeMillis=1631187753113;_LevelValue=800;|
      Payara Notification Service bootstrapped.|#]
    
    [#|2021-09-09T11:42:33.138+0000|INFO|Payara 5.2021.6|monitoring-console-core|_ThreadID=1;_ThreadName=main;_TimeMillis=1631187753138;_LevelValue=800;|
      Bootstrapping Monitoring Console Runtime|#]
    
    [#|2021-09-09T11:42:33.166+0000|INFO|Payara 5.2021.6|monitoring-console-core|_ThreadID=1;_ThreadName=main;_TimeMillis=1631187753166;_LevelValue=800;|
      Starting monitoring data collection for server|#]
    
    [#|2021-09-09T11:42:33.167+0000|INFO|Payara 5.2021.6|monitoring-console-core|_ThreadID=1;_ThreadName=main;_TimeMillis=1631187753167;_LevelValue=800;|
      Starting monitoring watch collection for server|#]
    
    [#|2021-09-09T11:42:33.299+0000|INFO|Payara 5.2021.6|javax.enterprise.system.core|_ThreadID=26;_ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1631187749111;_TimeMillis=1631187753299;_LevelValue=800;_MessageID=NCLS-CORE-00101;|
      Network Listener JMS_PROXY_default_JMS_host started in: 2ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:7676]|#]
    
    [#|2021-09-09T11:42:33.308+0000|INFO|Payara 5.2021.6||_ThreadID=1;_ThreadName=main;_TimeMillis=1631187753308;_LevelValue=800;|
      Reading in commandments from /opt/payara/config/post-boot-commands-final.asadmin|#]
    
    [#|2021-09-09T11:42:33.482+0000|INFO|Payara 5.2021.6|javax.enterprise.system.jmx|_ThreadID=122;_ThreadName=Thread-13;_TimeMillis=1631187753482;_LevelValue=800;_MessageID=NCLS-JMX-00024;|
      Creating a SecureRMIServerSocketFactory @ 0.0.0.0 with ssl config = GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.grizzly.config.dom.Ssl|#]
    
    [#|2021-09-09T11:42:33.494+0000|WARNING|Payara 5.2021.6|javax.enterprise.system.jmx|_ThreadID=122;_ThreadName=Thread-13;_TimeMillis=1631187753494;_LevelValue=900;_MessageID=NCLS-JMX-00020;|
      All SSL cipher suites disabled for network-listener(s).  Using SSL implementation specific defaults|#]
    
    [#|2021-09-09T11:42:33.518+0000|WARNING|Payara 5.2021.6|javax.enterprise.system.jmx|_ThreadID=122;_ThreadName=Thread-13;_TimeMillis=1631187753518;_LevelValue=900;_MessageID=NCLS-JMX-00020;|
      All SSL cipher suites disabled for network-listener(s).  Using SSL implementation specific defaults|#]
    
    [#|2021-09-09T11:42:33.557+0000|INFO|Payara 5.2021.6|org.jvnet.hk2.osgiadapter|_ThreadID=20;_ThreadName=FelixStartLevel;_TimeMillis=1631187753557;_LevelValue=800;|
      Skipping registration of inhabitant for service reference [org.osgi.service.metatype.MetaTypeProvider] as the service object could not be obtained.|#]
    
    [#|2021-09-09T11:42:33.612+0000|INFO|Payara 5.2021.6|javax.enterprise.system.jmx|_ThreadID=122;_ThreadName=Thread-13;_TimeMillis=1631187753612;_LevelValue=800;_MessageID=NCLS-JMX-00025;|
      SSLServerSocket /0.0.0.0:8686 and [SSL: ServerSocket[addr=/0.0.0.0,localport=8686]] created|#]
    
    [#|2021-09-09T11:42:34.058+0000|INFO|Payara 5.2021.6|javax.enterprise.system.jmx|_ThreadID=122;_ThreadName=Thread-13;_TimeMillis=1631187754058;_LevelValue=800;_MessageID=NCLS-JMX-00005;|
      JMXStartupService has started JMXConnector on JMXService URL service:jmx:rmi://0.0.0.0:8686/jndi/rmi://0.0.0.0:8686/jmxrmi|#]
    
    [#|2021-09-09T11:42:34.755+0000|INFO|Payara 5.2021.6|javax.enterprise.resource.corba.org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.api|_ThreadID=1;_ThreadName=main;_TimeMillis=1631187754755;_LevelValue=800;|
      GlassFishORBFactory service initialized.|#]
    
    [#|2021-09-09T11:42:34.909+0000|INFO|Payara 5.2021.6|javax.enterprise.system.core.security|_ThreadID=1;_ThreadName=main;_TimeMillis=1631187754909;_LevelValue=800;_MessageID=NCLS-SECURITY-01002;|
      Java security manager is disabled.|#]
    
    [#|2021-09-09T11:42:34.910+0000|INFO|Payara 5.2021.6|javax.enterprise.system.core.security|_ThreadID=1;_ThreadName=main;_TimeMillis=1631187754910;_LevelValue=800;_MessageID=NCLS-SECURITY-01010;|
      Entering Security Startup Service.|#]
    
    [#|2021-09-09T11:42:34.913+0000|INFO|Payara 5.2021.6|javax.enterprise.system.core.security|_ThreadID=1;_ThreadName=main;_TimeMillis=1631187754913;_LevelValue=800;_MessageID=NCLS-SECURITY-01143;|
      Loading policy provider com.sun.enterprise.security.provider.PolicyWrapper.|#]
    
    [#|2021-09-09T11:42:34.943+0000|INFO|Payara 5.2021.6|javax.enterprise.system.core.security|_ThreadID=1;_ThreadName=main;_TimeMillis=1631187754943;_LevelValue=800;_MessageID=NCLS-SECURITY-01011;|
      Security Service(s) started successfully.|#]
    
    [#|2021-09-09T11:42:34.994+0000|INFO|Payara 5.2021.6|javax.enterprise.webservices.metroglue|_ThreadID=1;_ThreadName=main;_TimeMillis=1631187754994;_LevelValue=800;_MessageID=AS-WSMETROGLUE-10010;|
      Web service endpoint deployment events listener registered successfully.|#]
    
    [#|2021-09-09T11:42:35.191+0000|INFO|Payara 5.2021.6|javax.enterprise.web|_ThreadID=1;_ThreadName=main;_TimeMillis=1631187755191;_LevelValue=800;_MessageID=AS-WEB-GLUE-00198;|
      Created HTTP listener http-listener-1 on host/port 0.0.0.0:8080|#]
    
    [#|2021-09-09T11:42:35.196+0000|INFO|Payara 5.2021.6|javax.enterprise.web|_ThreadID=1;_ThreadName=main;_TimeMillis=1631187755196;_LevelValue=800;_MessageID=AS-WEB-GLUE-00198;|
      Created HTTP listener http-listener-2 on host/port 0.0.0.0:8181|#]
    
    [#|2021-09-09T11:42:35.198+0000|INFO|Payara 5.2021.6|javax.enterprise.web|_ThreadID=1;_ThreadName=main;_TimeMillis=1631187755198;_LevelValue=800;_MessageID=AS-WEB-GLUE-00198;|
      Created HTTP listener admin-listener on host/port 0.0.0.0:4848|#]
    
    [#|2021-09-09T11:42:35.223+0000|INFO|Payara 5.2021.6|javax.enterprise.web|_ThreadID=1;_ThreadName=main;_TimeMillis=1631187755223;_LevelValue=800;_MessageID=AS-WEB-GLUE-00200;|
      Created virtual server server|#]
    
    [#|2021-09-09T11:42:35.226+0000|INFO|Payara 5.2021.6|javax.enterprise.web|_ThreadID=1;_ThreadName=main;_TimeMillis=1631187755226;_LevelValue=800;_MessageID=AS-WEB-GLUE-00200;|
      Created virtual server __asadmin|#]
    
    [#|2021-09-09T11:42:35.362+0000|INFO|Payara 5.2021.6|javax.enterprise.web|_ThreadID=1;_ThreadName=main;_TimeMillis=1631187755362;_LevelValue=800;_MessageID=AS-WEB-GLUE-00201;|
      Virtual server server loaded default web module |#]
    
    [#|2021-09-09T11:42:36.117+0000|SEVERE|Payara 5.2021.6|javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.dol|_ThreadID=1;_ThreadName=main;_TimeMillis=1631187756117;_LevelValue=1000;_MessageID=AS-DEPLOYMENT-00026;|
      JNDI lookup failed for the resource: Name: icat, Lookup: jdbc/icat, Type: javax.sql.DataSource.|#]
    
    [#|2021-09-09T11:42:36.120+0000|SEVERE|Payara 5.2021.6|javax.enterprise.system.core|_ThreadID=1;_ThreadName=main;_TimeMillis=1631187756120;_LevelValue=1000;|
      JNDI lookup failed for the resource: Name: [icat], Lookup: [jdbc/icat], Type: [javax.sql.DataSource] -- Lookup failed for 'jdbc/icat' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming}|#]
    
    [#|2021-09-09T11:42:36.194+0000|WARNING|Payara 5.2021.6|fish.payara.boot.runtime.BootCommand|_ThreadID=1;_ThreadName=main;_TimeMillis=1631187756194;_LevelValue=900;|
      Boot Command deploy failed PlainTextActionReporterFAILUREDescription: deploy AdminCommandError occurred during deployment: JNDI lookup failed for the resource: Name: [icat], Lookup: [jdbc/icat], Type: [javax.sql.DataSource] -- Lookup failed for 'jdbc/icat' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming}. Please see server.log for more details.
        [name=icat.server-4.11.1
     |#]
```

Comment: can you please add any logs or errors you're getting? like from the container, the terminal, the browser before and after and any other material you can send

Comment: Thanks, i've added them to the post. Just to point out that the war file doesn't successfully deploy, but it doesn't seem to try until the second run

Comment: It looks like it's added the deployment onto the post command but only trying to deploy it once it's restarted, is this normal?

Comment: I found a pdf which gives more details about the docker setup [link](https://info.payara.fish/using-payara-server-with-docker-guide). Got to sign up though. There it mentions:
"If you wish to have the application deploy upon creation and startup of the Payara Server instances within the containers, you must create a deployment group and deploy the application to this. You must then pass this deployment group as a parameter to the Docker container to add the instance to it upon startup"

Comment: if it was helpful did it solve your issue?

Comment: @Noam not sure yet, need to figure out how to "create a deployment group" as it doesn't say how to do this, currently trying different stuff out. Googling just brings me back here :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue should be fixed in the next release, version 5.2021.7. There has already been an issue raised on GitHub [here](https://github.com/payara/Payara/issues/5391) and an accompanying PR [here](https://github.com/payara/Payara/pull/5397)

Comment: Thanks @Kalin, that's great. Do you happen to know the release schedule, so I might know roughly when the fix is out?

Comment: Hi @WhatTheWhat, the planned date for release is the 15th of September 2021. However, this date may be delayed for unexpected reasons.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. I can confirm it now tries to deploy the application on start up